# Undefined array key "email"

Tags: php, laravel, auth-guard

I can't seems to find the reason why it gives me the error Undefined array key "email"
I'm sorry in advance if the info that I'm providing is not enough please tell me what info you guys need.

here is my admin controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->all();
            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($data);
            // die;

            if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password'], 'status' => 1])) {
                return redirect('admin/dashboard');
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error_message', 'Invalid Email or Password');
            }
        }
        return view('admin.login');
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guard = 'admin';
}
```

I already try changing the ['email' => $data['email'] to $data['email'] = 'example@example.com'

but it just give me the error that i have to migrate again which i'm not aiming for, should i migrate?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... your request doesn't appear to have an input named `email`, that is it

Comment: What was the output of the `print_r($data);` ? Did you have email filed there?

Comment: ow yah i don't have an email there

Array
(
    [_token] => uH8utGdQ60a5JtNjLaMmOByHEElOVnXncivvzcLq
    [password] => 123456
)

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: hey guys thanks for your response i found the problem i'm missing a " name="email" " hahah my bad, thank you for responding tho highly appreciated, i'm still new to laravel and php.